# BlackBerry | CAM:MMAPIVideoViewfinderField CameraRunnable function(7) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, blackberry

I have an app that initial has been developed for `OS 6.0`. Now I'm trying to run it on `OS 7.1` (Blackberry 9790). This app have a code that make recording video. But after call `Player.stop()` I see exception in another thread:

```
Thread [net_rim_services_impl(10)id=228570112] (Suspended (exception OutOfMemoryError)) 
    CameraController.StopViewfinder(int, boolean, boolean) line: 909    
    Camera.pauseViewfinder(int) line: 767   
    MMAPIVideoViewfinderField$CameraRunnable.run() line: 1049   
    Proxy(Application).dispatchInvokeLater(Runnable, Object, int) line: 1807    
    Proxy(Application).doProcessNextMessage(Message) line: 2501 
    Proxy(Application).processNextMessage(Message, boolean) line: 1916  
    Proxy(Application).enterEventDispatcher() line: 1709    
    ServiceStartup.tier0() line: 93 
    ServiceStartup.main(String[]) line: 17
```

Event log

```
[40191.88] CamController:StopVF
[40191.88] CamStopVF buf=0
[40191.88] net_rim_services_impl
[40191.945] RX=29.9M,RF=102.6M,FF=221.1M,OF=1.1M,OS=23.8M,ON=240.9K,OR=0,FR=18K,TR=22.3K,RR=3,IS=25.6K
[40191.945] RA=32.8M,RS=23.8M,RN=142.5K
[40191.945] TA=2.6M,TS=0,TN=3.8K
[40191.945] PA=0,PS=0,PN=10.8K
[40191.945] R0=60.1M,1=3.7M,2=25K,3=199.1K,4=1.3M,7=1.1M,8=7K,9=25.4M,10=58.4K,11=78.3K,12=928.4K,13=20.6K,14=2.[40191.945] 3K,15=767.8K,20=8K,21=1K,22=131.2K,23=271K,24=30K
[40191.953] CAM:MMAPIVideoViewfinderField CameraRunnable function(7) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
[40191.992] Signal level only changed - ONS not updated
[40192.016] CamController:UnLockSettings: skipping
```

On OS 6.0 version I wasn't faced with this issue

Maybe someone faced with similar issues too, and know how to fix it?

**Update1**
The same problem as in this thread http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Getting-quot-Media-Exception-Media-cannot-start-while-another/td-p/1244839

Comment: exception OutOfMemoryError ?

Comment: Yes. I know that it would be more correct to say Error instead Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to `7.1 Bundle 2039 (v7.1.0.714, Platform 9.16.0.158) helps me